# Allocate each value, considering what would be inserted

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, query

I'm stuck in a challenge where maybe you can help me.

This is what my data sets for the tables look like:

#### entities

```
Object 
Payment 
Invoice 
InvoiceItem
Payoff
```

- Object has N payments
- Invoice has N invoice items
- Payment has many payoffs
- Invoice items have many payoffs
- Payoffs is the **new** N-N break entity between invoice item and payments

Object ->payments -> payoff <- invoiceItem <- invoice

#### object

```
id.  amount.    name
1.   500.           Iphone
2.   20.             Additional cover for iPhone
3.   100.           Fuel
```

#### payment

```
id       amount         object.     desc
1        400            1        first collect
2        40             1         second payment
3        20             2        Paid with cc
4        100            3.       Transaction Kk2b
```

#### invoice

```
Id         total.       paid.      name
1          400.        true       Jonny
2          19.          true       Jonny
3          100.        true       Manuel
4          ...
```

#### invoice_item

```
Id        Invoice         object          amount
1         1               1               400
2         2               1               9
3         2               2               10
4         3               3               100
```

I created a table `invoice_payoff` like this:

```
create table invoice_payoff (
 id (int 11) primary key auto increment, 
 payment int(11),
 invoice int(11)
 Invoice_item int(11)
 amount decimal(10,2)
)
```

How can I assign, using a query (no stored procedure here), the value of the table payment to cover each invoice?

So as to fill `invoice_payoff`.

As suggested from comments I try to rappresent the final result of invoice_payoff

#### Example payoffs

```
Id.       Payment.        Invoice.         I.Item  amount
1.      1     1       1     400
2.      2      2       2     9
3.      3      2       3     10
4.      4      3       3     100
```

How the amount comes up

- The first payment(relative to obj1) of 400 can cover the invoice of 400.
- The second payment (relative to obj1 too) can cover the invoice item of 9, so just 9 are used and 31 leaved alone.
- The third payment can cover the invoice item of 10 relative to object 2.
- 4th payment covers the only invoice item of the 4th invoice, 3rd element

What I've tried:

1. Before this issue, I've already joined all tables and generated the payments for all invoices that was registered as paid. For this payments is easy to generate the payoff because one payment, one payoff.
2. I tried to retrieve the sub query of available payments for each invoice, sort them by decreasing price, and selecting the first one that can cover the invoice. I was near to create a valid script, but I think it wasn't enough because theorically I should have to execute the script many times.

Comment: Your data is a little confusing to me... You should try to get something setup in sqlfiddle online for free and then provide a link for people to help with the data right then

Comment: How payment table is linked with invoice_item and payment? May be you need to check your sample data again as the data presented in invoice table should have value 19 for invoice 2. Please confirm. Better if you can share Database schema diagram or explanation about it.

Comment: what MySQL version, I'm wondering in an answer can use CTEs?

Comment: @KapilBhagchandani you are right, the amount of the invoice is 19. The payment could be greater or lower than the amount of the invoice. The 'object' is what links payment to invoice_item

Comment: @danblack mysql 5.5

Comment: what query(s) have you tried so far, and what results are being generated? what are you expecting to see as the final contents of `invoice_payoff`? consider taking at look at [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and update your question

Comment: @markp added, I will provide a sqlfiddle asap

Comment: @KapilBhagchandani Added some scheme information, thank you

Comment: An `ORDER BY` in a subquery will be ignored, thereby invalidating (I think) your basic principle.  Read about @variables to keep track of stuff from one row to the next.